# Check if any string has a length, concatenate or use OR?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have 5 strings I need to check the length of in an if conditional, which is true if any of the string lengths != 0.

Normally you'd see this:

```
if(strlen($1) != 0 || strlen($2) != 0 || strlen($3) != 0 || strlen($4) != 0 || strlen($5) != 0){}
```

but I was sitting here thinking it *feels* (whether it is or not is a different matter) inefficient to have all those OR clauses.

So, I tried:

```
if(strlen($1.$2.$3.$4.$5) != 0){}
```

and of course it works. However, I am wondering if there is any reason I should **not** concatenate these strings together in a strlen to check, whether it be performance or potential logical issue. Seeing as all that needs to be done is check whether any string has length, I don't see a downside.

Comment: If you like it, use it

Comment: Starting a question with "Opinion" on Stack Overflow is a great way to get it closed.

Comment: Calling `strlen` once would obviously be faster than calling `strlen` multiple times.

Comment: @mistermartin But does that outweigh the cost of concatenating several strings together (see [shlemiel the painter](http://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter))?

Comment: I would say use whatever keeps the code the most readable (which sometimes may look like bloat)! Or if you do something like above, it's obviously fine too - if it gives result expected, but make sure you comment the code! As shown below speed difference (in the grand scheme of things) is negligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some benchmarks with:

```
$a = $b = $c = $d = $e = '';

$t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    if(strlen($a) != 0 || strlen($b) != 0 || strlen($c) != 0 || strlen($d) != 0 || strlen($e) != 0){}
}
echo 'using || : ',(microtime(true) - $t),"\n";

$t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    if(strlen($a) != 0 or strlen($b) != 0 or strlen($c) != 0 or strlen($d) != 0 or strlen($e) != 0){}
}
echo 'using or : ',(microtime(true) - $t),"\n";

$t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    if(strlen($a.$b.$c.$d.$e) != 0){} 
}
echo 'concat : ',(microtime(true) - $t),"\n";
```

I get:

run #1:

```
using || : 0.1004638671875
using or : 0.066226959228516
concat : 0.030498027801514
```

run #2:

```
using || : 0.088317155838013
using or : 0.082902908325195
concat : 0.06523609161377
```

run #3:

```
using || : 0.081311225891113
using or : 0.064895153045654
concat : 0.028335809707642
```

run #4

```
using || : 0.099178075790405
using or : 0.093825101852417
concat : 0.048026084899902
```

run #5:

```
using || : 0.091998100280762
using or : 0.064527034759521
concat : 0.031124114990234
```

**Conclusion:**

Concatenate seems quicker than the others 2 or 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

If it were in javascript I'd see only a problem if one these values is undefined when you need to concatenate

Answer (score 0):

I think it's with your preference.

But the readability of what you are tring to say could be changed according to what you are using.